# Extracting contents of anchor tag BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

So I've been trying to extract the contents of the anchor tag, using , .contents, .get_text(), various css selectors, but none seem to work. I've looked at various other questions and tried the solutions but they still haven't worked. I'm finding an anchor tag using:

```
import requests
page = requests.get('https://fasttrack.grv.org.au/RaceField/ViewRaces/338181522')
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
print(soup.select("div#DogName_1_1 a"))
```

Currently I get:

```
[<a href="/Dog/Form?id=2131520026" rel="dog-summary-link">MERCURY RISING [M]</a>]
```

But all I want is:

MERCURY RISING [M]

Thanks for your time in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `text` attribute:

```
>>> import requests
>>> page = requests.get('https://fasttrack.grv.org.au/RaceField/ViewRaces/338181522')
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
>>> print([ i.text for i in soup.select("div#DogName_1_1 a")])
['MERCURY RISING [M]']
```

If it is just one element you are interested in, you may want to do something like:

```
>>> soup.find(id='DogName_1_1').text
'\nMERCURY RISING [M]\n'
```

If you want to get rid of the trailing/leading `\n`s you can use [`strip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip):

```
>>> soup.find(id='DogName_1_1').text.strip()
'MERCURY RISING [M]'
```